# How to programatically construct and execute a DAG of callables specified in a configuration file

Tags: python, config, directed-acyclic-graphs, callable-object

I have a graph with a fixed number of nodes, where each node posses a dictionary of callables. I want to be able to programmatically construct a sequence of interactions between these nodes' callables from a config file.

For instance, I might want to specify the following sequence of interactions:

1. Call Node 1's `A()` function
2. Pass the output to Node 2's `A()` callable (which is different than Node 1's `A` callable) and Node 3's `B()` callable
3. Pass the outputs from both callables to Node 1's `B()` callable

The sequence of function calls and how information flows between them forms a directed acyclic graph (DAG). How do I programmatically construct and execute the DAG from a config file?

Comment: Looks like a job for airflow: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: Oh, that is awesome! I had no idea this existed. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jlandercy does this require distributed computing? Does the config work for calling functions on a single machine inside one process?